# How to map multiple states to props by using Redux in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm kind of newbie to react and I'm trying to fetch data from a couple of actions - in one component, so my goal is to do this :

Suppose I have a component name 
Inside it I want to do this :

```js
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchGenres();
    this.props.fetchMovies();
}
```

And in the export area :

```js
AllMovies.propTypes = {
  fetchMovies: propTypes.func.isRequired,
  fetchGenres: propTypes.func.isRequired,
  genres: propTypes.array.isRequired,
  movies: propTypes.array.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  genres: state.genres,
  movies: state.movies.items,
  newMovie: state.movies.item,
  editedMovie: state.movies.item
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchMovies, fetchGenres }
)(AllMovies);
```

If I use only one map in the  "export default connect" , I receive no errors - but when I add another to the connect object- I get errors

So my question is - is this the right way to map multiple states to props?

Comment: What fo you mean by another `map`? In redux there is only one state. Why would you need another `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: One mapStateToProps gets you all the states from redux store and make them available as props through connect method then why would you need another mapStateToProps ?

Comment: if you want to pass functions add it in the mapStateToProps instead of passing it as a part of dispatch. Try adding fetchMovies: fetchMovies, fetchGenres: fetchGenres inside mapStateToProps

Answer (score 4):

I see nothing wrong with your code, but perhaps you didn't import your action creators when you passed them to the second parameter of connect? It'll show something like - `ReferenceError: fetchMovies is not defined`. If so this is thrown by your attempt to pass `{fetchMovies, fetchGenres}` to the `connect` function not your code within `componentWillMount()`.

```
// Import statements
import { fetchMovies, fetchGenres } from '/path/to/actionCreators';


// Your react component somewhere here.


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    // This is the longhand of what you did
    return {
        genres: state.genres,
        movies: state.movies.items,
        newMovie: state.movies.item,
        editedMovie: state.movies.item
    };
};

/**
 * It's generally more clear to have mapDispatchToProps 
 * as a variable instead of passing the object directly 
 * to the connect. It's not wrong though. Make sure these
 * are imported.
 */

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchMovies
    fetchGenres
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use "bindActionCreators" to bind the redux actions. So your code will be like this:

```js
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as genreActionCreators from '@redux/actions/genre-actions'; // Path to the file containing the redux action fetchGenres().
import * as movieActionCreators from '@redux/actions/movie-actions'; // Path to the file containing the redux action fetchMovies().

class AllMovies extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.actions.genres.fetchGenres();
    this.props.actions.movies.fetchMovies();
  }

  // Rest of the component code

}

AllMovies.propTypes = {
  fetchMovies: propTypes.func.isRequired,
  fetchGenres: propTypes.func.isRequired,
  genres: propTypes.array.isRequired,
  movies: propTypes.array.isRequired
};

// Subscribing the component to redux store changes.
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    genres: state.genres,
    movies: state.movies.items,
    newMovie: state.movies.item,
    editedMovie: state.movies.item
  };
}

// Enables the component to dispatch actions
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: {
      movies: bindActionCreators(movieActionCreators, dispatch),
      genres: bindActionCreators(genreActionCreators, dispatch),
    },
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AllMovies);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!